# How would I manipulate this recipe (or another) to make Jäger Bomb flavoured macarons?

Tags: baking, macarons

It's my brother's birthday and he loves Jägermeister so was thinking of making Jäger Bomb flavoured macarons.  Red Bull flavoured pastry and Jäger flavoured cream.

I saw this recipe: https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/macarons

How would you manipulate (or is there another you'd recommend) to make Jäger Bomb flavoured macarons?

I was thinking add few tablespoons of Jäger to the cream but I'm worried the pastry will be too wet if I add Red Bull.

Comment: Do the pastry have to be Red bull flavoured ? In the recipe you link they do a filling with cream and raspberry jam, couldnt you substitute the jam with a redbull equivalent? Maybe reduce Red bull to a thicker, spreadable consistency or mix with gelatine and make disks that you then put on one side of the macron and the cream on the other.

Comment: Please, if you settle on a recipe and it works (even halfway decently), respond and post what you ended up doing. This sounds like a fun treat to make.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Macaron halves aren't pastry, they are a type of meringue, I'm assuming you aren't making pastry too.

You can't add red bull to the macaron sides, it will ruin the consistency and you won't get lift. Instead you need to add a flavoring concentrate, and you are in luck because you can actually buy red bull flavoring in some places,or energy drink flavoring which is similar. This is likely pretty strong so you'll want to be careful adding it, too much will be overpowering. In fact, if you are new to macarons I would suggest making at least one batch beforehand as they are tricky little so-and-sos to make.

The cream is much more flexible, you can add Jagermeister to that and still get a good consistency, again test how much works. A handy trick is to coat the flat side of the macaron halves with a thin layer of white chocolate, this will keep them from getting soggy from the cream.

Asking for recipe alternatives is off-topic, my advice would be the same for most of them anyway: don't use red bull but a flavor concentrate. If you are looking for something less technically challenging you could do a cake and icing, as those work well with flavorings, just start with a cake that is unflavored to begin with or your flavorings will clash, a white cake recipe for example.

Comment: `You can't add red bull to the macaron sides, it will ruin the consistency and you won't get lift.` So what you're saying is RedBull doesn't give you wings after all?

Comment: WARNING: The company mentioned to buy flavouring is dissolved: https://find-and-update.company-information.service.gov.uk/company/12610006 they took my money and did not respond (no fault of GdD the company was disloved 3 months ago)

Comment: I've taken that link out, I was only showing an example, really sorry about that @rosh3000! If you paid on a credit card call the card provider and report it, you should be able to get your money back. Same with Paypal